# Converting code to MVC type in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a php file that contains a form inside it

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form_map">
    <input type="text" name="post_code" id="post_code"
        class="field" value="" />
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="View" />
    <span id="saveToDb">SAVE MAP</span> 
</form>
```

When the submit button was clicked, an external javascript file will be called wherein the values inside the form will be accessed.

```
$(function() {
     $('#form_map').submit(function() {
          //process codes
     });
     ....
});
```

inside this javascript file contains a code that will call for another php file

```
var mapObject = {
....
urlCall : 'mod/gg.php',
urlSave : 'mod/save.php',
```

Without using code igniter, it works well. But when i use code igniter, the gg.php & save.php could no longer be located. 404 not found from the console

Is there a good approach that I could do to solve it? I was thinking that i should call a controller first for it to work, but im not sure if that would solve the problem and if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Codeigniter, your url should change to something like `controller/function`, so , define [base_url()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) in js variable like:

```
var BASE_URL = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
```

and your js, change:

```
var mapObject = {
....
urlCall : 'mod/gg.php',
urlSave : 'mod/save.php',
```

to

```
var mapObject = {
....
urlCall : BASE_URL + 'mod/ggfunction',
urlSave : BASE_URL + 'mod/savefunction',
```

where `mod` is your Controller, and `ggfunction` & `savefunction` are functions inside `mod` Controller.

Comment: Thank you. It worked even without the declaration of base_url

Answer (score 1):

All files you will request via Ajax must be controllers. So you have to create for example a Controller named "Mod" with a "gg" and a "save" action. Then you have to replace the urls in your javascript with the correct routes to those controller actions.